# How to build a high-performance inserted index for unordered fields

Tags: mysql, database

I now have a table that needs to insert about 2,000 pieces of data per second. There is an unordered Bigint field that needs to be built into an index. However, I found that the performance cannot meet the demand. Is there any good way?

Comment: Every index is ordered by definition. If you do not need ordering - simply remove the index.

Comment: I need to be able to query records in a table with tens of millions of data. If there is no index, it will be very slow It's just that the order cannot be predicted when inserting

Comment: Like I said - every index has an order, otherwise it is not an index. From a theoretical point of view, it does not matter in what sequence you add items to the index - it will always remain sorted. From a practical point of view - some sequences are faster to insert than others, but quering speed will stay roughly the same (with an accent on **roughly**) - exactly because the indexes have this wonderful **sorted/ordered** property.

Comment: More details, please.  Is that 2000 _rows_?  In a single "batch" `INSERT`?  Or 2000 1-row inserts?  Single transaction?  `AUTO_INCREMENT`, or are you setting the `BIGINT`?  Is it the `PRIMARY KEY`?  Using InnoDB?  How many columns?  Any `TEXT` columns?  What thing is "unordered"?  Etc.

Comment: Insert 2000 entries at a time,InnoDB is used,There are about 16 column. The field to be indexed is the mobile number